# Neovim: no syntax highlighting with treesitter for markdown

Tags: markdown, neovim, treesitter

It actually works with the [Kickstart](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim) setup, but stops working as soon as I change the `coloscheme` to anything else. None of the color schemes that came with the AppImage distribution seem to highlight neither simple Markdown, nor the Hugo-style Markdown with YAML "front matter".

When I set `additional_vim_regex_highlighting = true`, everything is highlighted as expected, but that means two things are doing the same job. Removing treesitter altogether also works, but the highlighting for other things is not as detailed.

```
NVIM v0.9.5
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.1692716794
```

Output of `:checkhealth nvim-treesitter`:

```
nvim-treesitter: require("nvim-treesitter.health").check()

Installation ~
- WARNING `tree-sitter` executable not found (parser generator, only needed for :TSInstallFromGrammar, not required for :TSInstall)
- WARNING `node` executable not found (only needed for :TSInstallFromGrammar, not required for :TSInstall)
- OK `git` executable found.
- OK `cc` executable found. Selected from { vim.NIL, "cc", "gcc", "clang", "cl", "zig" }
  Version: cc (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0
- OK Neovim was compiled with tree-sitter runtime ABI version 14 (required >=13). Parsers must be compatible with runtime ABI.

OS Info:
{
  machine = "x86_64",
  release = "5.14.21-150400.24.100-default",
  sysname = "Linux",
  version = "#1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Dec 4 19:12:13 UTC 2023 (3f5cd84)"
} ~

Parser/Features         H L F I J
  - bash                ✓ ✓ ✓ . ✓
  - c                   ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓
  - dockerfile          ✓ . . . ✓
  - elixir              ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓
  - gitignore           ✓ . . . .
  - go                  ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓
  - gomod               ✓ . . . ✓
  - gosum               ✓ . . . .
  - gotmpl              ✓ . . . ✓
  - gowork              ✓ . . . ✓
  - heex                ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓
  - html                ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓
  - javascript          ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓
  - json                ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ .
  - lua                 ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓
  - markdown            ✓ . ✓ ✓ ✓
  - markdown_inline     ✓ . . . ✓
  - python              ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓
  - query               ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓
  - vim                 ✓ ✓ ✓ . ✓
  - vimdoc              ✓ . . . ✓
  - yaml                ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓ ✓

  Legend: H[ighlight], L[ocals], F[olds], I[ndents], In[j]ections
         +) multiple parsers found, only one will be used
         x) errors found in the query, try to run :TSUpdate {lang} ~
```

I'm not quite sure where the problem lies. Is it parser? A color scheme? If it is anything to do with color scheme, is there a list of the ones supported by treesitter?

Comment: There is alot of threads about this same issue, [1](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/issues/5397), [2](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/issues/4915), [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/rg97j4/treesitter_for_markdown/). Try updating `:TSUpdate all`

Comment: @Tribhuwan  I did it (and a few other things) before posting, thank you.